# How to upload Android sqlite BLOB data into MySQL BLOB

Tags: android, mysql, android-sqlite

I am developing a project where user store some information and image into SQLite database. The image is stored as BLOB data. Now I want to upload all data into my MySQL database. I am using Volley to upload all rows one by one from SQLite to MySQL server with a AsyncTask calling a Web API.

Everything working fine without the image BLOB data. I do not know is there any way to upload blob data using Volley.
I have search a lot into StackOverflow but did not get any solution, please help me.

I am giving some code example to make my question better understandable.

Here is my function calling in a AsyncTask:

```
/**
 * function to upload data into server
 * */
private void SyncTaskDoInBack(final dataDB data) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "Inserting Online";

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST, AppConfig.API_LINK, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                // Check for error node in json
                if (!error) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Success");
                } else {
                    // Error in found
                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ID", data._id);
            params.put("PersonName", data.pName);
            params.put("Photo", data.photo.toString());

            return params;
        }

    };

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

My "dataDB" Class is as follows:

```
public class dataDB implements Comparable<dataDB>{

    String _id = null;
    String pName = null;
    byte[] photo = null;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(dataDB o) {
        //return title.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.title.toLowerCase());
        return 0;
    }

}
```

List Data Model class is follows:

```
public class ListDataModel {

private int _id;
private String name;
private byte[] image;

public ListDataModel() { }

public ListDataModel(String name, String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.name = name;
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

// getting ID
public int getID() {
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int keyId) {
    this._id = keyId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public byte[] getImage() {
    return this.image;
}

public void setImage(byte[] image) {
    this.image = image;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot into StackOverflow, I have come up with the following formula, which appears to produce the camera image into Base64 String and Vice-versa. Hope this will help others.

I am using *Apache Commons Codec* for Base64 encode/decode from here http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/ *(I think one can use Android default Base64 class too, I am using this for other purposes also)*

Here is my **onActivityResult** function

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
        return;

    switch (requestCode) {

        case CAMERA_REQUEST:

            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

            if (extras != null) {

                Bitmap myImage = extras.getParcelable("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                myImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bao);

                imageInByte = bao.toByteArray();

                imageInBase64Str = Base64.encodeBytes(imageInByte); // using internal class
            }

            break;
    }
}
```

Then I'm passing the Base64 String **imageInBase64Str** to my insert statement of SQlite and MySQL online database.

When getting image Base64 encoded data from SQLite or MySQL to view, I'm processing my image like the following way:

```
 try {
        byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(imageData, 0);
        theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
 }catch (IOException io){
        Log.d("ViewRecord",io.getMessage());
 }
```

That's it :)